# What is the difference between GL_EXT_texture_compression_dxt1 and GL_EXT_texture_compression_s3tc

Tags: opengl, opengl-es

when I try to see OpenGL Extensions in my PC, it shows up the below two extensions among other many extensions

```
GL_EXT_texture_compression_dxt1

GL_EXT_texture_compression_s3tc
```

I looked up in the internet and it says s3tc is called by DXTn. That means s3tc and DXTs are basically same algorithm:
  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S3_Texture_Compression

I have set of questions:

1. Then, why my PC shows the same compression algorithm with two different items.
2. I also see the following extension

   GL_ANGLE_texture_compression_dxt5

I understand that it provides dxt5 compression, but why does it start with GL_ANGLE and how does it different to GL_EXT prefix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[GL_EXT_texture_compression_s3tc](https://www.opengl.org/registry/specs/EXT/texture_compression_s3tc.txt) provides support for DTX1, DTX3, and DTX5 compressed textures. From what I've read, virtually every modern GPU supports it.

From reading it's spec, [GL_EXT_texture_compression_dxt1](https://www.opengl.org/registry/specs/EXT/texture_compression_dxt1.txt) is a slimmed down version of GL_EXT_texture_compression_s3tc primarily targeted for OpenGL ES; it only supports DTX1 and doesn't support compressing the textures for you. Since it's a subset of the previous extension, the driver can report that it supports both extensions.

In addition to the ARB and EXT prefixes, there are some extensions that are vendor specific, which are prefixed with the vendor name (ex. `GL_NV_texture_barrier` and `GL_AMD_pinned_memory`). GL_ANGLE is apparently for extensions specific to the [ANGLE project](https://code.google.com/p/angleproject/). According to it's spec, [GL_ANGLE_texture_compression_dxt5](https://www.khronos.org/registry/gles/extensions/ANGLE/ANGLE_texture_compression_dxt.txt) is an extension to GL_EXT_texture_compression_dxt1 that supports DTX5.